# How to apply wide_n_deep tutorial on multi-class classification issue?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the wide_n_deep tutorial code, the below two line:

```
df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df_train["label"].apply(lambda x: '>50K' in x)).astype(int)
df_test[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df_test["label"].apply(lambda x: '>50K' in x)).astype(int)
```

change the label column from `string` to `int`. However, it seems that this kind of operation only works well on two-classes classification data sets, i.e, `yes` or `no`, `1` or `0` problems.

Now I hope to apply the wide and deep model on more classes, especially numerical data than string data. But I got 
`TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable`

I have also tried to delete the codes transforming label columns to `int`, which
shown above, and I got 
`tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.monitors.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.`

So how can I solve those problems?
Can't the wide_n_deep model make use for multi-classification?

Answer (score 0):

The wide&deep estimators do support multiclass classification if you produce labels in a larger range than 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on a float column :

```
df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = df_train["float_column"].astype(float)
```

But I have 0.0 accuracy ... maybe this not the right answer but it shows no errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking to solve this. tf r1.1 has an argument n_classes

```
estimator = DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
# common settings
n_classes=n_classes,
weight_column_name=weight_column_name,
# wide settings
linear_feature_columns=[sparse_feature_a_x_sparse_feature_b],
linear_optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(...),
# deep settings
dnn_feature_columns=[sparse_feature_a_emb, sparse_feature_b_emb],
dnn_hidden_units=[1000, 500, 100],
dnn_optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(...))
```

> n_classes: number of label classes. Default is binary classification.
>   Note that class labels are integers representing the class index (i.e.
>   values from 0 to n_classes-1). For arbitrary label values (e.g. string
>   labels), convert to class indices first.

[Link to doc's](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNLinearCombinedClassifier#predict_classes)